# Pygal World Map - mouseover features

Tags: python, pygal

I'm using Python's Pygal World Map module.  Put simply, I want "2016" to pop up when the cursor hovers over the United States.  When I hover over the United States, however, I do not get any mouseover effect.  I'm trying to achieve the mouseover effect on Pygal's website: http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html

```
import pygal

wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.title = 'Countries I\'ve Been To'
wm.add('United States',{'us':2016})

wm.render_to_file('myplaces.svg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please open the `.svg` file **with Google Chrome** and you will see the mouseover features.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding the line

```
wm.force_uri_protocol = 'http'
```

to your code. I think Pygal changed the way tooltips are rendered when they moved from 1.9 to 2.0.

This program should work:

```
import pygal

wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.force_uri_protocol = 'http'
wm.title = 'Countries I\'ve Been To'
wm.add('United States',{'us':2016})

wm.render_to_file('myplaces.svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pygal_maps_world plugin use command `pip` / `pip3 install pygal_maps_world`.

```
import pygal.maps.world
wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
```